# How to check if an input string is part of any component of any tuple

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

I am having issues with using an input string and checking to see if it is part of a tuple in the data list.

```
data = [(Mr. John Doe, 345.678.9765, johndoe@gmail.com),
        (Ms. Mary Doe, 345.123.4567, marydoe@gmail.com)]
print("Search for: ")
s = input()
while s:
   for a in data:
    if any(b[0] == s for b in a):
        print(a)
    else:
        print("Not Found")
print("Search for: ")
s = input()
```

If I enter in `Mr.` as the input it will fail to find the component in the tuple, but if I enter `j` as the input it will print out:

```
 (Mr. John Doe, 345.678.9765, johndoe@gmail.com)
```

Comment: Try `str.startswith` instead...

Comment: Use the built in `any` function: `any(any(s in item for item in tup) for tup in data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any(b[0] == s for b in a)` will only be `True` if the user inputs the full name exactly as it is in name string, (e.g. `Mr. John Doe`). Instead, check if the user input is ***in*** any part of the name string using the `in` operator:

```
data = [('Mr. John Doe', '345.678.9765', 'johndoe@gmail.com'),
        ('Ms. Mary Doe', '345.123.4567', 'marydoe@gmail.com')]

print("Search for: ")

s = input()

result = None # set a variable to hold our result

for a in data:
    if any(s in b for b in a): # use in to check if substring 's' is in string 'b'
        result = a[0]  # save the name that contains user input
        break          # exit loop if found
    else:
        result = "Not Found"

print(result)
```

The reason it was failing with `Mr.` input is because `b[0]` in `b[0] == s for b in a` refers to the first letter in each string in the tuple, and a 3-character string will never equal a single character.

Similarly, when we input `j`, the comparison `b[0] == s for b in a` *does* match the first character in the last string of the first tuple (`j` in `johndoe@gmail.com`), so it *did* output that tuple.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I really appreciate it!

Comment: Very welcome! if my answer is helpful please consider up-voting it (click the up arrow next to the answer), or if it solved your problem consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) by clicking the green check mark. Thanks!